# How would I change how arguments are passed to a string.format() function depending how how many there are?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I am trying to write something to take strings from a txt file and input them into an array. I was doing it by manually inputting them and using interpolated strings but that is becoming unfeasible now. I need to be able to change parts of the string depending on the result of a function, and on any given string there could 0 to any number of parts that need to be changed. I figured this would work in theory but that there *had* to be a better way:

```
 public void formatStringInSentencesArray(int numOfArgs, int arrIndexToBeFormatted, UnityAction[] funcsToBePutIn)
    {
        if (numOfArgs == 1)
        {
            conversation[index].sentences[arrIndexToBeFormatted] = string.Format(conversation[index].sentences[arrIndexToBeFormatted], funcsToBePutIn[0]);
        }
    ...
        else if (numOfArgs == 5)
        {
            conversation[index].sentences[arrIndexToBeFormatted] = string.Format(conversation[index].sentences[arrIndexToBeFormatted], funcsToBePutIn[0], funcsToBePutIn[1], funcsToBePutIn[2], funcsToBePutIn[3], funcsToBePutIn[4]);
        }
```

Is there any way I could go about doing this in a way that isn't just a hacked together bunch of ifs and else ifs? (This is all written in C# for a unity game btw)

Comment: else ... if constructs usually indicate you should be useing a switch/case in that place. They were given pattern matching ability a while back. | The params mechanic might be the droid you asked for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

string.format already supports arrays. Is this what you're looking for?

```
var paramArray = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
var output = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", paramArray);
```

Based on your example, I'd probably replace your function with:

```
conversation[index].sentences[arrIndexToBeFormatted] = string.Format(conversation[index].sentences[arrIndexToBeFormatted], funcsToBePutIn);
```

Comment: I did not know that, yeah that would be about what I need, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> By using the params keyword, you can specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments. The parameter type must be a single-dimensional array.
>
> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a method declaration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

The compiler will deal with turning that line of Arguments into a single array.

The `String.Format()` - and function that use it like `Console.WriteLine()` - use the params keyword. The main function behaves as if it does, but given that the data comes from the OS it is possible it is not using the keyword (making the array is somebody elses job).